# How to read lines of dictionary and write to a CSV file

Tags: python

I have a data file, the format is like this

```
{"Name":"David","Age":"14","Score":[0,1]}
{"Name":"Jason","Age":"12","Score":[0,0]}
```

my question is :
1) How do i read this file and convert to CSV

```
Name,Age,Score
David,14,0/1
Jason,12,0
```

2) How do I convert to [0,1] to 0/1, [0,0] to 0, means when denominator is a zero, the result is 0, otherwise, take the 1st number to divide by the 2nd number inside the []

Thanks!!

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: is your file format is exactly like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start the data appears to be JSON encoded, so you can use the [**`json`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json) module to read it into a list of dictionaries:

```
import json

with open('input') as f:
    dicts = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
```

For your sample data `dicts` will be set to:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dicts)
[{u'Age': u'14', u'Name': u'David', u'Score': [0, 1]},
 {u'Age': u'12', u'Name': u'Jason', u'Score': [0, 0]}]
```

Update the scores (assuming that you actually want to perform the division):

```
for d in dicts:
    score = d['Score']
    d['Score'] = score[0]/score[1] if score[1] != 0 else 0
    #d['Score'] = '{}/{}'.format(score[0], score[1]) if score[1] != 0 else '0'
```

(the above line will generate a textual version of the division operation, if that is what was wanted)

Next you can use a [**`csv.DictWriter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) object to write the output to a CSV file.

```
import csv

with open('output', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['Age', 'Name', 'Score'])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(dicts)
```

Finally, your output file should contain:

```
Age,Name,Score
14,David,0
12,Jason,0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by learning how to open a file and read lines

[Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

After that learn how to extract substring of string with a specific formats

[Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

And learn how to write in a file after that

[Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

With theses links I think you can try something and return here and create a question with your code on it. Without your own code you asking us to program for you.

Comment: thank you, I did try to write some code, but got some error msg which I worried had something to do with my source file and i was worried my error msg my mislead the answers.